# picker not loading data

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a detail view with several textfields, next to one of them i have a button a user can click to pop up a single component picker.  the picker is hidden till the user clicks the button.  just to make sure that the basics work, I have a simple array assignd to the pickerdata.  the button to show the picker works but the data doesn't show up, here is the code

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed 
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data", @"data 1", nil]; 
    self.pickerData = array;
    vPicker.hidden = NO;
    selectButton.hidden = NO;   
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
{ 
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return [pickerData count]; 
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include UIPickerview datasource and delegate in the interface of your class..then set vpicker.datasource = self and vpicker.delegate= self;

Comment: On iPhone that's why the code can have some mistakes and also the answer is not properly formatted.. Hope you don't mind.. If any problem let me know

Comment: thanks.  I actually just added a line to [vPicker reloadAllComponents] and it seems to show the data now.

Comment: sorry about the formatting, total noob -- even here and trying to figure it out...